# Does Genie.j v1.1 support user login & admin views?

Tags: julia

I am interested in using some of my Django knowledge to build a web app in Julia. I found [Genie.jl](https://genieframework.github.io/Genie.jl/dev/index.html) and it looks promising. However, I did not see any reference to setting up user login and such. Does this exist within Genie as it is a core element of the Django experience
I need to recreate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to work for me.

However as of today lots work on `Genie` docs is needed and hence I am not sure whether this is optimal.

```
using Genie, Genie.Router, Genie.Requests,Genie.Responses, Genie.Sessions

route("/favicon.ico",() -> "")
route("/") do
    "<html><body>
    <form action=/mylogin>
    Login <input name=login><br>Pass <input name=pass><br><input type=submit></form>
    </body></html>"
end

Sessions.init()
data = Dict{String,String}()
route("/mylogin") do
    login = get(@params, :login, "")
    pass = get(@params, :pass, "")
    if length(strip(login)) > 0 && login == pass
        sid = Sessions.id()
        sess, resp = Sessions.start(sid, request(), getresponse())
        data[sid] = login
        return("<body><html>started session $sid for a user $login<br><a href=/checksession>check status</a>  </body></html>")
    else
        return("<body><html>Wrong user or password</body></html>")
    end
end



route("/checksession") do
    sid = Sessions.id(request())
    login = get(data, sid, nothing)
    if isnothing(login)
        return("<body><html>No user session</html>")
    else
        return("<body><html>Current user $login at session $sid</body></html>")
    end
end

Genie.AppServer.startup()
```